# how can i use the sports data in my solidity smartcontract?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, chainlink

which was the best and low cost API for the sports data to access for my contract in DAPP ?

1. please share me any docs or code snippets if available.

Answer (score 0):

What is the best depends on your situation.

If the sport data required is general data like match results of NFL, NBA, MLB, etc., or you don't have an access to official API or you don't have resources to setup and maintain an infrastructure for the workflow, you can rely on Chainlink node operators to provide the specific data.

In this way, what you need to do is simply send request to a node operator and then the node will write data into your contract with a callback function. You need to pay data providers fees so that they can at least cover the gas fees in transactions.

You can find sample codes showing how to send request to a Chainlink node operator in [official docs](https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/single-word-response), and you can also find node operators [here](https://market.link/overview?searchView=true&searchSection=DATA_PROVIDERS), for example [SportsMonks](https://market.link/nodes/SportMonks) is one of data providers to provide sports-related data.

If you need your data updated frequently or the what you need is niche data like result of LOL which is not supported by any data providers that can be found. In the scenario, you probably want to set up your own Chainlink node and fetch sport data from specific API. In this way, you don't need to pay fees to node operators. You can find videos about Chainlink node setup [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO3O6ZUtwbs).

Hope it helps!